# TypeError: books.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a react app.
I have 2 files

1. AuthorQuiz.js
2. index.js

And I have 2 components

1. AuthorQuiz
2. Turn

Turn component is embedded in the AuthorQuiz component and the AuthorQuiz is the main component.

And data is coming from **index.js** as a spread operator

**AuthorQuiz.js**

```
function AuthorQuiz({ turnData }) {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
       <Turn {...turnData} />
    </div>
  );
}


function Turn(author, books) {
  return (
    <div className="row turn" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <div className="col-4 offset-1">
        <img src={author.imageUrl} className="authorImage" alt="Author" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-6">
        {books.map(title => (
          <p>{title}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**index.js**

```
const authors = [
  {
    name: 'Mark Twain',
    imageUrl: 'images/authors/marktwain.jpg',
    imageSource: 'Wikimedia Commons',
    books: ['The Adventures of Hucklebery Finn']
  }
];

const state = {
  turnData: {
    author: authors[0],
    books: authors[0].books
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<AuthorQuiz {...state} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

but when I run my code I get an error

**TypeError: books.map is not a function**

Comment: try this:

`function Turn({author, books}) {`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't destructured the props in Turn component, which leads to it being treated incorrectly by the component

```
function Turn({ author, books }) { // Destructure props here
  return (
    <div className="row turn" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <div className="col-4 offset-1">
        <img src={author.imageUrl} className="authorImage" alt="Author" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-6">
        {books.map(title => (
          <p>{title}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: how can I destructure?

Comment: @user2983359, I did show it in my example, `function Turn({ author, books }) {`

Comment: Glad to have helped